# about the order of the elements in a set

Tags: coq

I have the following definitions:

```
Definition n : set string := ("a" :: "b" :: nil).
Definition m : set (set string) := ("b" :: "a" :: nil) :: ("c" :: "d" :: nil) :: nil.
```

I try to prove the following:

```
Example n_in_m : set_In n m.
Proof.
  unfold n . unfold m.
  simpl.
```

after doing 'simpl', the goal becomes:

```
"b" :: "a" :: nil = "a" :: "b" :: nil \/
"c" :: "d" :: nil = "a" :: "b" :: nil \/ False
```

then i don't know how to go on the proof! Is it right the order of the element in a set doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to prove that:

```
{a, b} ∈ { {b, a}, {c, d} }
```

but your set membership is defined with regards to propositional equality. The problem is that the two objects:

```
("a" :: "b" :: nil)
```

and:

```
("b" :: "a" :: nil)
```

are not propositionally equal.

---

You probably want to use instead a richer definition for `set`, one that is parameterized by when two elements are to be considered equal.

Comment: yes, but how to define a richer definition for set? do you mean a new definition for set? thanks!